# php regex preg wont match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

PHP REGEX

```
// Search Field:
$e = "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'KM0403580-70' for key 'PRIMARY'"

// Code:
$errorRegex = ereg("\:.([0-9]+)[a-zA-Z\s]+'([A-Z]*)'$", $e, $moError);
echo $moError[2] . "  " . $moError[1];
```

Trying to get:

1. `1062`
2. `KM0403580-70`

Any idea's what I'm doing wrong? I've been trying to find out for 4 hours now haha

Comment: `ereg` is obsolete for a while now, please use `preg_match` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the regex you are trying to write, although it will probably match a lot of things besides just your data...

```
^.*: ([0-9]+).* '([A-Z0-9-]+)'.*$
```

Something like this would be much *safer* in that it would only find id codes from your specific type of error:

```
^SQLSTATE\[[0-9]+\]: Integrity constraint violation: ([0-9]+) Duplicate entry '([A-Z0-9-]+)' for key 'PRIMARY'$
```